# Get Marker on Google Maps via name of Business

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, web-services, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am building a website, and on it I have a Google Map. I also have a list of business names, e.g. WH Smith, Manchester.

Assuming there is only one in Manchester, how can I get a Marker showing on my Map the location of the WH Smith branch?

I tried searching, but found nothing on the subject !

Comment: You mean something like [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_places-searchboxC.html?q=WH%20Smith,%20Manchester.)?  Looks like the assumption about on WH Smith in Manchester isn't very good...

Comment: OMG ! Yes EXACTLY like that ! It works too, if you add UK after the Manchester :) Is there an API I can use for that?

Comment: Wait a second, are you saying that functionality is already built into Google Maps API v3? geocodezip.com, seems to be only a list of tutorials .. am I right?

Comment: That example is using the [Google Maps Places API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I do it is to set up an array of locations, each of which is an array of the necessary information, in the order html for tooltip, latitude, longitude, title. I get the Latitude and Longitude from this site: http://universimmedia.pagesperso-orange.fr/geo/loc.htm So you would just type in the city center.

```
function initialize() {         
                geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

                var businesslocations = [

                        ['HTML TO DISPLAY ON TOOLTIP', LATITUDE, LONGITUDE,'LOCATION NAME'], 
                        ['HTML TO DISPLAY ON TOOLTIP', LATITUDE, LONGITUDE,'LOCATION NAME'],
```

Finish that array off, then do your other map settings. Then set up the map. Then set up its markers programmatically using that array. The for loop goes through the different locations, and then pulls out the 4 elements of the array.

```
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

            var marker, x;

            for (x = 0; x < businesslocations.length; x++) {  
              var latllong = new google.maps.LatLng(businesslocations[x][1], businesslocations[x][2]);
              marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlong,
                map: map,
                title: businesslocations[i][3]
              });
              bounds.extend(latlong);

              google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, x) {
                return function() {
                  infowindow.setContent(businesslocations[x][0]);
                  infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
              })(marker, x));
            }

            map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Comment: Thanks Hobbes, the issue is I have no Lat and Lang information. All I have is the name of the business. And from that I want an accurate marker on the Map. Is there no way of achieving this?

Comment: Well you just have to look them up. The website I gave ( http://universimmedia.pagesperso-orange.fr/geo/loc.htm  ) well let you type in a city and then give you the lat and long.

Comment: Even if I knew how to look them up programatically (I don't), that still wouldn't give me an accurate Marker. A city is huge, and I need the Marker on the address of the Business. Does Google Places not tie in with Google Maps in any way? :(

Comment: So you want to programatically do a google places search for a particular business based just on the name and city, hope it gets you the right one, and then programatically pull that location information into your code?

Comment: Exactly. Can I use Google Places to pull place detailed information? For example I can pull Waterstone's address in Oxford from that. Then can I not use the Post Code and Building number to get the Lat and Lang from Google Maps? Or perhaps can I place the marker by using the Post Code and building number alone?

Comment: Well, I suppose it might be possible, but it's beyond my knowledge. You're talking about interfacing with two different APIs and hoping everything runs smoothly. The only reason I would ever want to take on that headache is for a non-static collection of data, i.e. it's going to change all the time. Even for 100 locations you would spend less time doing it manually. Plus Google places listings are just too inaccurate to trust they will always work like that without extensive checks. Your example (WH Smith Mancester) brought up 7 different results.

Comment: Yep my data is always changing. But I think you might be right, I have around 200 locations Max. Do you think it would be better to write down the lat and lang for all them locations manually?

Comment: Probably. I would put them into excel file as you get them so it will be easy to make your array later (or a good text editor with search and replace). If you're talking daily data updates I would think about storing the information in a database like mySQL and making yourself a form to edit them with. Weekly or monthly updates, just do it manually. Remember what you were looking for might be possible, I've just never seen a cut-and-paste solution for it so it might be more work than then hour and a half it would take to do it manually. Hope that's helpful!